# How can i count the numbers in every subset?

Tags: r, frequency

I have several subset like this

```
s1 <- c(0,-1,0)  
s2 <- c(0,1,0) 
s3 <- c(0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

If I want to count the number"-4" 
 for example

```
"-4"doesn't show up in s1 ,freq=0;

"-4"doesn't show up in s2 ,freq=0;

"-4"doesn't show up in s3 ,freq=0;
```

It should be reveal that frequency=0

instead

for example

```
"1"doesn't show up in s1 ,freq=0;

"1"does show up in s2 ,freq=1;

"1"does show up in s3 ,freq=2;
```

What can i do that i can get the frequency??

Comment: Suppose if `s1` has -4 and other two doesn't.  So, is it still `0`

Comment: @Rorita_Tai Freq of `1` in `s3`  is `3`.  What is the final output for the second example?

Comment: it does show up in s3,so it counts 1

Comment: @Rorita_Tai Does this work `cumsum(sapply(Map('==', list(s1,s2,s3),1),any))#[1] 0 1 2`

Comment: @Rorita_Tai Wouldn't it be better if you provide some clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list then use lapply

```
MyList <- list("s1"=s1, "s2"=s2, "s3"=s3)
lapply(MyList,function(x) length(x[x == -4])
```

The result is a list with the count of `-4` for each list element

You can replace `lapply` with `sapply` if you want a vector of counts instead of a list, this can be useful if you want the total count instead of the per element count.

Comment: I think `sum(x==-4)` would be shorter

Comment: Maybe, but summing a logical vector isn't very intuitive.

Comment: @JeremyS: If you are a coding enthusiast, the target audience of SO, then summing a logical vector _should_ be intuitive. Look up the works of the 19th century logician George Boole.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many vectors and don't want to enter them all manually into your data, you could do:

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "^s\\d+$"))   # to create a list of the vectors
sum(unlist(lst) == 4)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Nice trick with that variable name pattern! :)

Answer (score 1):

This shows a couple of ways of accessing the results of the dots argument:

```
 fn <- function(..., target)
  {  for ( i in seq_along( list(...) ) ){ 
        if( vl <- length( which( target == list(...)[[i]] ))){ 
               cat(target,"does show up in ") 
               objname <- deparse(substitute(list(...))[[i+1]])
               cat(objname,";length=",vl, "\n")
          } else{ 
              cat(target,"doesn't show up in ") 
              objname <- deparse(substitute(list(...))[[i+1]])
              cat(objname, "\n") }
     } }

 fn( s1,s2,s3, target=1)
1 doesn't show up in s1 
1 does show up in s2 ;length= 1 
1 does show up in s3 ;length= 3
```